# How to change 1 to zeros in the binary form in C

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, operators, bitwise-operators

I can't figure out how to change any consecutive 1 to zeros in the binary form of x (consecutive 1 means a set of 1 that contains more than one 1).

Problem specifications:
Allowed operators: ! ~ & ^ | + << >> (no loops or other control constructs)
Maximum number of operators: 16

Examples

- cleanConsecutive1(0x10) = 0x10
- cleanConsecutive1(0xF0) = 0x0
- cleanConsecutive1(0xFFFF0001) = 0x1
- cleanConsecutive1(0x4F4F4F4F) = 0x40404040

This is what I tried so far

```
int cleanConsecutive1(int x) {
    x = (x | (x >> 1)) & ~(x & (x >> 1));
    x = (x | (x >> 2)) & ~(x & (x >> 2));
    x = (x | (x >> 4)) & ~(x & (x >> 4));
    x = (x | (x >> 8)) & ~(x & (x >> 8));
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want `x` to be _signed_?

Comment: Can you explain the thinking behind your code? Maybe we can then point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm now thinking maybe I can do an XOR with two x's?

Comment: The easiest and most obvious is a loop, so the artificial requirements aren't very helpful.

Comment: It won't pass the tests with any control constructs, can only use at most 16 of these operators: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>

Comment: One solution is `static const uint32_t ridiculously_massive_LUT [UINT32_MAX] = { [0] = 0, [1] = 1, [2] = 2, [3] = 0, ...   };`  Then the function becomes `return ridiculously_massive_LUT [x];`

Comment: I can see OP is not rushing in with an explanation of what the code is trying to do. And the code does take a step in the right direction and then starts pointlessly running around. Is that from ChatGPT?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to understand the logic with ChatGPT but still don't really know how to approach this problem.

Comment: What "tests" do you have? What is the actual assignment? What are all its requirements and limitations?

Answer (score 3):

Five operations: `x & ~(x << 1 | x >> 1)`.

Shifting `x` left one and right one and ORing those gives a mask where each bit is set if there is a 1 adjacent to it in `x`. Then:

- Any isolated 1 in `x` does not have a 1 adjacent to it, so there is a 0 at that place in the mask.
- Any 1 in a group has a 1 adjacent to it, so there is a 1 at that place in the mask.
- A 0 may or may not have a 1 adjacent to it, but we do not care what is at that place in the mask because either 0 or 1 will work with the below.

Then the mask is used to turn off bits in `x` by complementing it and ANDing it with `x`. Per the above, this turns off each 1 bit that has an adjacent 1.

`x` should be unsigned or narrower than an `int` to avoid issues with the sign bit.

Comment: Nice! Just to be paranoid, I tested exhaustively with `uint32_t` data: no failures were observed. While it is five basic operations, it maps to as few as three machine instructions (e.g. ARM, NVIDIA GPUs).

Answer (score 2):

It can be done as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned cleanConsecutive1(unsigned x) {
    return x & ((~x >> 1) | ~(~(0u) >> 1)) & ((~x << 1) | 1);
    // Multi-line version:
    //   unsigned msb = ~(~(0u) >> 1);
    //   unsigned left_mask = (~x >> 1) | msb;
    //   unsigned right_mask = (~x << 1) | 1;
    //   return (x & left_mask & right_mask);
}

#define TEST(x) printf("0x%08x -> 0x%08x\n", x, cleanConsecutive1(x))

int main()
{
    TEST(0x10);
    TEST(0xF0);
    TEST(0xFFFF0001);
    TEST(0x4F4F4F4F);
}
```

Output:

```
0x00000010 -> 0x00000010
0x000000f0 -> 0x00000000
0xffff0001 -> 0x00000001
0x4f4f4f4f -> 0x40404040
```

The idea is to first mask off set bits except those to the right of an unset bit, then mask off set bits except those to the left of an unset bit. Thus only set bits having an unset bit to the left and right are remaining in the result.

In this context, there is an imaginary unset bit at both ends of the input. These are the bits we have to set by `|` in the masks.

I have changed the function to use `unsigned` instead of signed `int` since bit-shift operators are not well-defined for negative values.

Answer (score 1):

The bit-twiddling idiom I recognize in your GPT-given code is

```
x & ~(x & (x >> 1))
```

`x&(x>>1)` captures consecutive ones into a mask and then by clears them by using `not` and `and`

The snippet above would reduce consecutive ones to the highest bit in each run and clear the rest.

Can we reduce them to the lowest bit instead? Sure:

```
x & ~(x & (x << 1))
```

And we are clearing bits, so we can combine both:

```
x & ~(x & (x >> 1)) & ~(x & (x << 1))
```

seems to work.

Comment: `x << 1` is a problem (UB) for _signed_ types when a 1 is shifted into the sign bit.  Better with `unsigned cleanConsecutive1(unsigned x)`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
   unsigned cleanConsecutive2(unsigned x) {
       unsigned y = x & (x << 1);
       return x ^ (y | (y >> 1));
   }
```